# What is the origin of "get a shimmy on"

Tags: british-english

I'm British and understand this to mean "speed up" or "hurry up".

I can find references to it online, so it's not just me, but I can't find any reference in a dictionary or anything official.

From [Fresh on the net](http://freshonthenet.co.uk/2016/09/faves211/):

> With just one upcoming gig, at the Paper Dress in London on Thursday, you’ll have to **get a shimmy on** to get a ticket, but keep an eye on their Facebook page for more events.

From [What To Expect (comment)](http://www.whattoexpect.com/forums/may-2016-babies/topic/41-weeks-and-counting-who-39-s-with-me.html):

> I hope your baby decides to **get a shimmy on** soon and you will have to let us know when baby decides to join us!

Comment: It's probably a less humdrum-sounding improvement on 'get a move on'; the usages of 'shimmy' have broadened from the truncated noun to the corresponding verb [dance a shimmy-shake] to the sense 'move quickly and agilely'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand it to be a synonym of "shake", as in this dance/song:
[Bobby Freeman - (I Do the) Shimmy Shimmy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wR6_htIbZo)

Cf. Other, similar "hurry up" expressions include "shake a leg":
[Dictionary.com](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shake-a-leg)

Comment: Friends of mine in the UK use "shimmy" to mean a shortcut or deft manoeuvre, for example in traffic.

Comment: Anecdotally: The shimmy in english wikipedia is describing a belly dance move (exactly whay I expected) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimmy while the shimmy in german wikipedia describes a foxtrott-type dance (but including some bellydance-like moves).